# access Map through jquery inside spring model

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

How can I get the value of a Map key in spring mvc view page, with map passed to Model as below in controller:

```
 ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("addEvent");
 modelAndView.addObject("saveList", saveList);
 modelAndView.addObject("saveIDMap", saveIDMap);

 return modelAndView;
```

where saveIDMap is a `Map<String, Integer>`

The jquery code trying to access it in jsp page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#saveTypeID").on('change', function() {
       var val = $("#saveTypeID").val();       ----getting here successfully
       var saveId = "${saveIDMap['" + val + "']}";  ---trying to get hashmap value
       $("#saveIDID").val(saveID);
    });
   });
</script>
```

where the ids are in the form snippet below:

```
      <tr>  
      <td>SaveType :</td>  
      <td><form:select path="saveType" items="${saveList}" id ="saveTypeID"/></td>  
     </tr>  

     <tr>
     <td>SaveId :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="saveId" id="saveIDID"/></td>  
     </tr>
```

The JQuery code after the part to access saveIDMap is not running, and where do I see error messages for jquery in a tomcat container?

Please help! New to jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${saveIDMap[KEY]}" varStatus="status">
    <input type="text" id="saveID_${status.index}" value="${item.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

**item** will be each object in your map. You need to change input value based on your object.

Comment: Thanks, but when I access the item variable in javascript and dynamically append to saveID_ using + concatenation, it doesn't work. I am able to access hashmap directly in jquery using var saveId = "${saveIDMap['keyy']}"; where key is the actual key, but when keyy is dynamically populated like - var saveId = "$(saveIDMap['" + val + "'])"); where val is jquery variable, it doesn't work. same way I tried to access items like var saveId = "$(items['saveID_" + val + "'])"); Looks like might have a problem with the way jquery is concatenating string. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @tigger If i understand your case correctly, your problem is map you sent is rendered during the page load. After the page load you will not be able to access it. So, either you can save the map values on the page load as in my example and use based on user selection or you can fetch the data for each call with ajax.

Comment: I am able to access hashmap directly in jquery using var saveId = "${saveIDMap['keyy']}"; where key is the actual key.

Comment: So the map is able to be accessed, it's just that when I make the key dynamically in jquery, the access fails - same is happening when I try to access your saved map with a dynamic key, I am using string concatenation with + to make dynamic like: var saveId = "${saveIDMap['" + val + "']}"; where val is the key